# How to use tab for text auto complete system wide?

Tags: autocomplete, text-editing, tab-completion

Mac OS suggests completions of some text in some instances. A particular example would be when writing an email. The default way to choose the suggested text is to use the downward arrow to highlight the suggested text, then pressing 'return' to select it. *This behavior is not intuitive.*

Is there a way to change this?

I would prefer to use 'tab' to accept the suggested text.